# How to hide the dialog of MFC when I switch to other software interface

Tags: mfc, dialog

Now, I am showing a modal dialog when I click a button of my software

```
CDescDlg dlg(this);
if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) {
}
```

But, when I focus on other software, this dialog is still showing on the top of my screen.

How to hide this dialog when I switch my interface to other software? is it a attribute of this dialog? I cannot find the related materials.

Please help.

Comment: Make sure "Topmost" flag is false in dialogbox editor's properties window

Comment: Yeah. You are right. Things has changed. Thank you very much!